# how to transfer files from Kali?

Tags: kali-linux, usb, virtual-machine, vmware, bluetooth

I am using Kali Linux on virtual machine and i want to transfer a file from it to my phone. maybe blue-tooth or USB anything but i don't know how to do that or maybe i have to move it to my host operation system (windows) first.

Comment: Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/

Answer (score 0):

1. Email it.
2. Open a web browser and send it through a file transfer app like [Pushbullet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pushbullet.android) or [SendAnywhere](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estmob.android.sendanywhere)
3. Park the file in [Mega](https://mega.nz), [OneDrive](https://office.live.com/start/OneDrive.aspx) or [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive) and pick it up from the mobile phone.

Answer (score -2):

Install the [VirtualBox Guest Additions](https://www.kali.org/docs/virtualization/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-kali/) if not already installed, select `Devices -> Drag and Drop -> Bidirectional` in the menu bar and drag & drop your files to the Windows desktop.

Comment: i am using vmware

Comment: There's a drag & drop feature in [VMware Workstation Player](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Player-for-Windows/15.0/com.vmware.player.win.using.doc/GUID-81932397-8211-499E-925E-98FC73428636.html) if that's what you're using.

Comment: i can't install the vmware tools for some reason it gives me error

Comment: Have you tried [VMware Tools for a Kali Guest](https://www.kali.org/docs/virtualization/install-vmware-tools-kali-guest/)?

Comment: awesome man you are a life saver!!